# Change printer paper tray settings via powershell

Tags: powershell, printing, vbscript

I attempted to use the WMI-Object to change the paper tray settings in powershell. However I've just learned that the value i'm trying to change is read-only apprently. Could someone help me accomplish task via powershell or VBScript?

```
$printers = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_PrinterConfiguration | Where-Object {$_.Name -EQ "CHK.Checks"}
$printers.MediaType = 270
$printers.Put()
```

I attempted this and it did not work.

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful if you reported any error messages you received, or explicitly stated that you did not receive any error message. In the latter case, it would also be useful to know how you determined that 'it didn't work'.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Error messages here aren't going to be useful because as Jessica stated the value is Read Only which means WMI unfortunately won't work.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin The error was "Exception calling "Put" with "0" argument(s): "Provider is not capable of the attempted operation "" which i researched and was lead to a page that told me it is read only.

Comment: Which @BenH stated, is not useful here. Thanks for clarifying Ben!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the value is read-only you won't be able to use WMI to set that. .Net has the `System.Printing` has an input bin setting, which isn't perfect but works. I've made a function around this in my [PSPrintTools](https://github.com/BenHimsel/PSPrintTools/tree/master/PSPrintTools) module. I think Tray1, Tray2 work as values as well, but I don't remember off the top of my head. Outside of this then you get into editing the PrintTicket XML. Here's the relevant code for just that feature:

```
$Printer = "Example Printer Name"
$InputBin = "AutoSelect","AutoSheetFeeder","Cassette","Manual","Tractor" #choose one
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Printing
$Permissions = [System.Printing.PrintSystemDesiredAccess]::AdministrateServer
$QueuePerms = [System.Printing.PrintSystemDesiredAccess]::AdministratePrinter
$PrintServer = new-object System.Printing.LocalPrintServer -ArgumentList $Permissions
$NewQueue = New-Object System.Printing.PrintQueue -ArgumentList $PrintServer,$Printer,1,$QueuePerms
$InputBinCaps = $NewQueue.GetPrintCapabilities().InputBinCapability
if ($null -ne $InputBinCaps) {
    if ($InputBinCaps.Contains([System.Printing.InputBin]::$InputBin)) {
        $NewQueue.DefaultPrintTicket.InputBin = [System.Printing.InputBin]::$InputBin
        $NewQueue.UserPrintTicket.InputBin = [System.Printing.InputBin]::$InputBin
    } else {
        Write-Error "$InputBin unavailable on $Printer"
    }
}
$NewQueue.commit()
$NewQueue.dispose()
$PrintServer.commit()
$PrintServer.dispose()
```

Comment: I executed your script. I had to add a closing "}" to the end of your if statement but it worked great for setting the tray! However, what I actually need to change is the "Paper Type" I need to set that value to preprinted as opposed to: "Use Printer Settings"

Comment: Fixed the missing {. That's what I get from cutting and pasting. Page size is nicer, it's the property `PageMediaType`. The GitHub module has that as a parameter to the `Set-PSPTPrintConfiguration` function as well or you can modify my code here to be `PageMediaType` rather than `InputBin`

Comment: Awesome I really appreciate the help that works. But it only works for the values populated into "GetPrintCapabilities().PageMediaTypeCapability" @BenH. Preprinted is not an option for that field. If i try to change it to bond, it works flawlessly. But preprinted returns: "Cannot find an overload for "Contains" and the argument count: "1"."

Comment: Right, there is a "Capability" property for each actual property in that class. It just lets you check that your printer can use that setting. Also if a answer works for you, you should accept it.

Comment: Preprinted isn't one of the values in that enumeration. Here's the [MSDN with all of them](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.pagemediatype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: is there anyway to add a property to the capability field?

Comment: Unfortunately not, settings that aren't in that enumeration make the value be `Unknown`. And you can't set it to `Unknown` here.

Comment: Is there another option to explore to get it to set to the value I need it to be? @BenH

Comment: I think manually creating the PrintTicketXML. Which you can then set with the `Set-PrintConfiguration -PrintTicketXml` on Win8 or newer systems